# sending callback out of subapplication in extjs

Tags: extjs

How can I send a callback out of a a subapplication ?

```
 Shopware.app.Application.addSubApplication({
        name: 'Shopware.apps.UploadManager',
        layout: 'small',
        eventScope: me,
        selectionMode: true,
        params: {
            uploadId:uploadId,
            number:number,
            position: position,
            orderID: orderID
        },
        callback: my_Function()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

"my_Function()" this means function call.

when you are defining an object just assign the function name to it "callback: my_Function"

try this,

```
Shopware.app.Application.addSubApplication({
        name: 'Shopware.apps.UploadManager',
        layout: 'small',
        eventScope: me,
        selectionMode: true,
        params: {
            uploadId:uploadId,
            number:number,
            position: position,
            orderID: orderID
        },
        callback: my_Function
    });
```

Comment: sorry I mean, how to send a callback in the subApplication. In this example Shopware.apps.UploadManager

Answer (score 0):

I got it by myself :-))

I put
var callback = me.subApplication.callback;

in the init function and the callback is called via

```
    if (callback) {
        callback.call(this, orderId);
    }
```